# having sorted multi column chart with unsorted series in highchart-ng module

Tags: json, sorting, highcharts

i want to have sorted column chart like  http://jsfiddle.net/z2agkzt0/2/
with unsorted series like this.
this series has three data row about 'Stockholm', 'Göteborg', 'Malmö'
that the highchart rendered by the y value in their data but the data are'nt 
sorted but i want a sorted chart like the jsfiddle link in the top.

```
  series: [{
        type: 'column',
        name: 'Stockholm',
        data: [{x:0, y:95, color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]}]
    }, {
        type: 'column',
        name: 'Göteborg',
        data: [{x:0, y:110, color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]}]
    }, {
        type: 'column',
        name: 'Malmö',
        data: [{x:0, y:70, color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2]}]
    }, {
        type: 'column',
        name: 'Göteborg',
        data: [{x: 1, name: 'February', y: 98, color:  
 Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1] // Göteborg's color
        }],
        showInLegend: false,
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: false
        }
    }, {
        type: 'column',
        name: 'Malmö',
        data: [{x: 1, name: 'February', y: 85, color: 
  Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2] // Stockholm's color
        }],
        showInLegend: false,
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: false
        }
    }, {
        type: 'column',
        name: 'Stockholm',
        data: [{x: 1, name: 'February', y: 100, color: 
  Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0] // Stockholm's color
        }],
        showInLegend: false,
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: false
        }
    }, {
        type: 'column',
        name: 'Göteborg',
        data: [{x: 2, name: 'Mars', y: 120, color: 
 Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1] // Göteborg's color
        }],
        showInLegend: false,
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: false
        }
    }, {
        type: 'column',
        name: 'Malmö',
        data: [{x: 2, name: 'Mars', y: 92, color: 
 Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2] // Stockholm's color
        }],
        showInLegend: false,
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: false
        }
    }, {
        type: 'column',
        name: 'Stockholm',
        data: [{x: 2, name: 'Mars', y: 90, color: 
  Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0] // Stockholm's color
        }],
        showInLegend: false,
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: false
        }
    }]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the order of the series.

```
series: [{
  type: 'column',
  name: 'Stockholm',
  data: [{
    x: 0,
    y: 95,
    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
  }]
}, {
  type: 'column',
  name: 'Göteborg',
  data: [{
    x: 0,
    y: 110,
    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
  }]
}, {
  type: 'column',
  name: 'Malmö',
  data: [{
    x: 0,
    y: 70,
    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2]
  }]
}, {
  type: 'column',
  name: 'Stockholm',
  data: [{
    x: 1,
    name: 'February',
    y: 100,
    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0] // Stockholm's color
  }],
  showInLegend: false,
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: false
  }
}, {
  type: 'column',
  name: 'Göteborg',
  data: [{
    x: 1,
    name: 'February',
    y: 98,
    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1] // Göteborg's color
  }],
  showInLegend: false,
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: false
  }
}, {
  type: 'column',
  name: 'Malmö',
  data: [{
    x: 1,
    name: 'February',
    y: 85,
    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2] // Stockholm's color
  }],
  showInLegend: false,
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: false
  }
}, {
  type: 'column',
  name: 'Stockholm',
  data: [{
    x: 2,
    name: 'Mars',
    y: 90,
    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0] // Stockholm's color
  }],
  showInLegend: false,
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: false
  }
}, {
  type: 'column',
  name: 'Göteborg',
  data: [{
    x: 2,
    name: 'Mars',
    y: 120,
    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1] // Göteborg's color
  }],
  showInLegend: false,
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: false
  }
}, {
  type: 'column',
  name: 'Malmö',
  data: [{
    x: 2,
    name: 'Mars',
    y: 92,
    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2] // Stockholm's color
  }],
  showInLegend: false,
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: false
  }
}]
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/z2agkzt0/5/

Comment: Thanks but id like a function that can sort this json